# GET http://localhost:8000/users/login 404 (Not Found)

Tags: angular

I am using passport Js for authentication.

I have tested the API through Postman and everything works fine. However, when I actually try to login using my signin page I am getting the following error :

GET http://localhost:8000/users/login 404 (Not Found)

```
//signin.html

<form class="px-4 py-3" [formGroup]="signinForm">
  <div class="input-group mb-3">
    <div class="input-group-prepend">
      <span class="input-group-text">@</span>
    </div>
    <input
      formControlName="username"
      type="text"
      class="form-control"
      placeholder="Email Address"
    />
  </div>
  <div class="input-group mb-3">
    <div class="input-group-prepend">
      <span class="input-group-text">#</span>
    </div>
    <input
      formControlName="password"
      type="password"
      class="form-control"
      placeholder="Password"
    />
  </div>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" (click)="login()">
    Sign In
  </button>
  <p style="color: white;margin-bottom: 0;margin-top: 2%;">
    New around here? <a [routerLink]="['/users/new']">Sign Up</a>
  </p>
</form>

//signin.component.ts

export class SigninComponent {
signinForm: FormGroup = new FormGroup({
username: new FormControl(null, [Validators.email, 
Validators.required]),
password: new FormControl(null, Validators.required)
});
constructor(private apiService: ApiserviceService, private router: 
Router) {}

login() {
if (!this.signinForm.valid) {
  console.log("Form Invalid");
  window.alert("Please Fill All Fields");
  return;
}
console.log(JSON.stringify(this.signinForm.value));
this.apiService
  .login(JSON.stringify(this.signinForm.value))
  .subscribe(data => {
    console.log(data);
  });
}
}

//apiservice.service.ts

login(body: any) {
return this.http.post("http://localhost:8000/users/login", body, {
  observe: "body"
});
}

//userRoutes.js

router.post(
"/users/login",
passport.authenticate("local", {
successRedirect: "/questions",
failureRedirect: "/signin"
}),
function(req, res) {}
);

//app-routing.module.ts

const routes: Routes = [
{ path: "question/:id/answer/new", component: AnswerComponent },
{ path: "question/:qId/answer/:aId/edit", component: 
EditanswerComponent }, 
{ path: "question/:id", component: AnswerComponent },
{ path: "questions/new", component: AskComponent },
{ path: "users/new", component: SignupComponent },
{ path: "signin", component: SigninComponent },
{ path: "questions", component: QuestionsComponent },
{ path: "answer", component: AnswerComponent },
{ path: "", redirectTo: "/users/new", pathMatch: "full" },
{ path: "**", component: PagenotfoundComponent }
];
```

GET http://localhost:8000/users/login 404 (Not Found)

Comment: show routing module pls

Comment: @sagat Added app-routing.module.ts.

Comment: mate did u serve on port 8000? Usually its port 4200.

Comment: @sagat My frontend is running on 4200 and backend on 8000

Comment: okay can u reach ur backend with postman

Comment: @sagat Yes I am able to reach backend with postman.

Comment: Trailing / on the POST route?

Comment: Any idea why your getting a GET error when your actually making a POST request?

Comment: @Nabel I have written the route properly.

Comment: @Mendy That is what I am confused about. I have used POST and I am getting a GET error.